# Check if Report is fully formatted

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

We have Order DB in Access where we collect and send Order confirmation to Clients. In Order Form I click button to open Confirmation Report in Normal view. I have "Send Report" button on opened report to send it to Client in PDF format.

All works grate with small reports. Problem arrise when report has 15-20 or more pages. After some investigation I found out that at time of report load user press Send button and report simply not being fully formated and sending action just fails.

I cannot find correct event to check if report is finished formatting. It would help me to make Send button enabled true/false based on that status.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use 'OnPrint' event of the report footer's section: "event occurs after data in a report section is formatted for printing, but before the section is printed"

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use it because this event does not fire on open for me. I do not print report. I am trying to open it in Normal view to be able to send it.

Comment: @litpost you don't print it to a printer but msaccess prints it to window. check its' behavior in sample report put `Debug.Print Now` line inside footer's `onprint` event.

Comment: I did what you sugegsted and nothing happened. OnPrint event did not fire at all. However if I open report in Print Preview mode then it works well. But I cannot use PrintPreview as I must have button on report to send it.

Comment: do you mean you have called `docmd.OpenReport "testreport",acViewNormal` and event didn't fire? then it is 2010 defect because 2003 works well with both 'acViewNormal' and 'acViewPreview' options.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it is 2010 defect maybe I can use another solution. Error trapping or onTimer event. When exactly OnTimer event starts on Report? I mean, after loading or somewhere in the process of loading?

Comment: Anyway I cannot use acViewNormal because I need to opent report first. Using acViewNormal report starts to print immediately w/o opening.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it at last.

- switched on docmd.Hourglass before button which opens the Report (button is located on Order Form) and switched off docmd.Hourglass on exit sub.
- in OnClick event of "Send" button at the top did the check for MousePointer

  If Screen.MousePointer = 11 Then Exit Sub

Now User is not able to start sending until all process of button on Order Form is finished. That is actualy strange but somehow it solved the issue. Thank you all for help!